NetCDF XArray time slice 12 midday 12 midnight NARR reanalysis data
stack overflow (think it's been over 10 years) but I am well and truly stuck!
I am trying to reduce the NARR reanalysis data to pass through a relatively simple calculation to replicate this analysis
The analysis states reduced the data set size by selecting the second half of the day 12 - 12 to identify the max value in that range. Xarray has the time slice function but I can't see anything about slicing a subset of hours per day just a date range?
is Xarray what I want to be using if so, how? If not, is there another package/approach which I should be utilising?
Time Array below:
array(['2022-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2022-01-01T03:00:00.000000000',
   '2022-01-01T06:00:00.000000000', ..., '2022-12-31T15:00:00.000000000',
   '2022-12-31T18:00:00.000000000', '2022-12-31T21:00:00.000000000'],
  dtype='datetime64[ns]')

Any help would be very much appreciated!

You can use Xarray's where to do more custom subsetting/slicing:
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.tutorial.open_dataset('air_temperature')
ds_subset = ds.where(ds.time.dt.hour > 12, drop=True)
#  is what you want


Perfect thank you so much! Seems so obvious now.
